# Calling an API with Promise returns undefined values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to get the value of the promise, but it says it is undefined every time.

I’m new to JavaScript, so sorry for being so bad...

For the function being called I didn’t put the whole code into the post, just the necessary information that it returns four floats. I tested that function.

I *updated* the code:

```js
async function getClosestSchachtInSeg(
  LON,
  LAT,
  FROMANGLE,
  TOANGLE,
  NS,
  maxCount
) {
  sqlQuery =
    "SELECT *, ST_X(ST_Transform (geom, 4326)) AS LON, ST_Y(ST_Transform (geom, 4326)) AS LAT," +
    " ST_Transform(SCHAECHTE_OWN.geom, 4326) <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(" +
    LON +
    ", " +
    LAT +
    "), 4326)::geometry AS dist " +
    ' FROM public."SCHAECHTE_OWN" SCHAECHTE_OWN ' +
    " WHERE atan((ST_X(ST_Transform (geom, 4326)) - " +
    LON +
    ") /  (ST_Y(ST_Transform (geom, 4326)) - " +
    LAT +
    ")) > " +
    FROMANGLE +
    "*pi()/180" +
    " AND atan((ST_X(ST_Transform (geom, 4326)) - " +
    LON +
    ") /  (ST_Y(ST_Transform (geom, 4326)) - " +
    LAT +
    ")) < " +
    TOANGLE +
    "*pi()/180" +
    " AND ST_Y(ST_Transform (geom, 4326)) " +
    NS +
    " " +
    LAT +
    " ORDER BY dist LIMIT " +
    maxCount +
    ";";

  pool
    .query(sqlQuery)
    .then((results) => {
      if (results.rows.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
          var ResLon = results.rows[i].lon;
          var ResLat = results.rows[i].lat;
          var ResDist = results.rows[i].dist;

          var urlDistance =
            "http://gisdatavm01hw.versatel.local:5001/getShortestPathLonLatDistance/" +
            Math.round(LON * 1000000) / 1000000 +
            "/" +
            Math.round(LAT * 1000000) / 1000000 +
            "/" +
            Math.round(results.rows[i].lon * 1000000) / 1000000 +
            "/" +
            Math.round(results.rows[i].lat * 1000000) / 1000000;

          //console.log(urlDistance);

          fetch(urlDistance)
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((body) => {
              //console.log(body);
              Dist = JSON.parse(body)["distance"];
              if (Dist) {
                return 10;
              }
            });
        }
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error("Error executing query", err.stack));
}

async function getClosestSchachtOWNJson12SegNew(request, response) {
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  response.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT"
  );
  response.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers"
  );
  //response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

  const LON = request.params.LON;
  const LAT = request.params.LAT;
  const maxCount = request.params.maxCount;

  Promise.resolve([
    getClosestSchachtInSeg(LON, LAT, -90, -60, ">=", maxCount),
    getClosestSchachtInSeg(LON, LAT, -60, -30, ">=", maxCount),
    getClosestSchachtInSeg(LON, LAT, -30, 0, ">=", maxCount),
    getClosestSchachtInSeg(LON, LAT, 0, 30, ">=", maxCount),
    getClosestSchachtInSeg(LON, LAT, 30, 60, ">=", maxCount),
    getClosestSchachtInSeg(LON, LAT, 60, 90, ">=", maxCount),
    getClosestSchachtInSeg(LON, LAT, -90, -60, "<", maxCount),
    getClosestSchachtInSeg(LON, LAT, -60, -30, "<", maxCount),
    getClosestSchachtInSeg(LON, LAT, -30, 0, "<", maxCount),
    getClosestSchachtInSeg(LON, LAT, 0, 30, "<", maxCount),
    getClosestSchachtInSeg(LON, LAT, 30, 60, "<", maxCount),
    getClosestSchachtInSeg(LON, LAT, 60, 90, "<", maxCount),
  ]).then((values) => {
    console.log(values);
  });
}
```

The output is:

```
[
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined }
]
```

Comment: `return float1,float2,float3,float4;` is the same as `return float4;`. `float4` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere but if it is it has the value `undefined`.

Comment: @FelixKling I added the complete code. At the moment where im printing it has the values and it is defined.

Comment: The fulfillment value you're turning from your `promise1.then` callback isn't used by anything, because nothing is using the promise that `promise1.then` returns. I suggest using `async`/`await` rather than directly writing promise callbacks, it's a bit simpler to understand.

Comment: You seem to be using explicit promise callbacks in an `async` function (i`getClosestSchachtInSeg`). It's best not to do that. Instead, use `await`.

Comment: I know you have your solution but I just wanted to point out that in your original code, the `getClosestSchachtInSeg` doesn't contain a `return` statement. So of course it returns `undefined`. And your `pool.query().then(...)` callback doesn't return anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting an await on the call to the async function getClosestSchachtInSeg.

Change:

```js
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  resolve(getClosestSchachtInSeg(LON,LAT,-90,-60,">=",maxCount));

});

promise1.then(result => {

  console.log(result);

  console.log(promise1);

  return result;

})
```

to:

```js
const result = await getClosestSchachtInSeg(LON, LAT, -90, -60, ">=", maxCount);
console.log(result);

// do what ya gotta do
```

Also, make `getClosestSchachtOWNJson12SegNew` an `async` function (so the `await`s above work — you can't use `await` in a non-`async` function).

Comment: It is still undefined

Comment: It's possible that the function that contains the line `const result = await getClosestSchachtInSeg(LON, LAT, -90, -60, ">=", maxCount)` is not marked as async? A constant cannot be marked as async however, so change it to a function and let me know how you go

Comment: I updated the code and also got now multiple promises. Sorry for changing so much...

Comment: Not sure I follow what you mean? You will need to `await` on `getClosestSchachtOWNJson12SegNew` after changing it to an `async` function

Comment: Please look at my code. I updated it in the question.

Comment: You also need to `await` the `pool.query` call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251116/discussion-between-codeode-and-zanderwar).